# Question about the definition of a function algebra separating points

Tags: real-analysis

The function algebra separates points if for each pair of distinct points $p_1, p_2 \in M$ there is a function $f \in \mathtt{A}$ such that $f(p_1) \neq f(p_2)$.

How can I visualize this notion of separating points?

Is this equivalent to saying that a function algebra does not separate points if for each pair of distinct points $p_1, p_2 \in M$, all functions $f \in \mathtt{A}$ satisfy the condition $f(p_1) = f(p_2)$?

Even if this is true, I'm for some reason having trouble wrapping my head around this pictorally. Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take all the functions $\;f:[-1,1]\to \Bbb R\;\;,\;\;s.t.\;\;f(-1)=f(1)\;$ . Check this is an algebra which doesn't fulfill the conditions of the Stone-Weirestrass Theorem. Think of this, perhaps now it'll be easier to see what's going on here.